# ASP.Net Web API DependencyResolver - Framework trying to resolve numerous internal dependencies that I don't care about?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

My small Web API project (hosted via `SelfHostHttpServer`) has a few dependencies I want to inject into the controllers. In order to do this, I have implemented `IDependencyResolver` and called `httpConfig.ServiceResolver.SetResolver`.

This *would* work fine, except it seems I need to satisfy the internal dependencies the Web API requires. The first time I ran it, I saw that it needed to resolve the controller factory, so I added an instance of `DefaultHttpControllerFactory` to my container. Now every damn time I refresh the page, it crashes with the *next* unresolved dependency the framework is trying to resolve.

Am I going about this the wrong way, or am I really supposed to try and guess all of the default implementations and be forced through this crash-fix-refresh cycle of discovering what dependencies are required for the Web API framework to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your resolver is doing in case it can't resolve the dependency? The proper behaviour should be returning null. ASP.NET Web API DependencyResolver (httpConfig.ServiceResolver) is internally using two resolvers:

- The one you set through SetResolver (user rosolver)
- The built in DefaultServiceResolver

If user resolver returns null for dependency then Web API falls back to DefaultServiceResolver which can handle all built-in dependencies.

Comment: Return null from GetService and an empty list from GetServices. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver